# Probability that 7 passengers don't get out of the bus for exactly 3 stops.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, combinations

There are 5 bus stops on a bus route, 7 passengers are traveling.

Each of them gets off at any of the stops before the end of the route and does not get back on.

What is the probability that no one will get off at exactly three of the stops?

My solution:

There are 3 bus stops that 0 people will get off at. That means that there are 2 bus stops remain available.

Let's pick 3 bus stations that will remain unused, it's possible to do so in 5C3 = 10 ways.

Getting out of the bus at the remaining two stops can go such ways:

• 1 person gets out in the first stop, 6 in the other,

• 2 in the first stop, 5 in the other,

• 3 in the first stop, 4 in the other,

... and vice versa.

Without any restrictions, there would be 5⁷ = 78125 ways to get out of the bus at any of the 5 bus stops.

Leaving the bus only in two bus stops is possible in 10 * 3 * 2 =  60 ways.

So, the probability is 60 / 78125 = 0.000768.
Am I correct?

Comment: Assuming each passenger's exit point is uniformly distributed, this is correct.

Comment: @RobertShore No. If there were one passenger with a choice of 5 stops, it would be $5^1$, not $1^5$. It is the choices that are multiplied, not the passengers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately neither comment written so far is correct.

Your count of $5^7$ (not $7^5$) overall possibilities is correct.

What you didn’t take into account is that is that you can choose different people to get off at the two stops. You can distribute $7$ people over $2$ bus stops in $2^7$ ways, but in $2$ of them they all get off at one of the stops, so the count is $2^7-2$, for a probability of

$$
\frac{\left(2^7-2\right)\binom53}{5^7}=\frac{252}{15625}\approx1.6\%\;.
$$